# On semi-group of operators

Tags: functional-analysis

W. Rudin. Functional Analysis (2nd Ed) $\S 13.34$ and $\S 13.35$.

$Q(t)$ is a semi-group of bounded linear operators on a Banach space $X$ for $t\in [0,\infty)$ such that
1) $Q(0) = 1$.
2) $Q(t+s)=Q(t)Q(s)$.
3) $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}||Q(\epsilon) x - x||=0\; \forall x\in X$.

It is shown that there exist reals $C(>0),\gamma$ such that $||Q(t)|| \le C\exp(\gamma t)\; \forall \;t\in [0,\infty)$ and that the map $t \mapsto Q(t)x$ is continuous $\forall x \in X$. Then the operator $M_t$ given by $$M_t x=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}Q(s)x \;ds$$ is well defined as integral of a vector valued function ($\S3.26-29$). The claim is that $$||M_t||\le C\exp(\gamma t).$$ For $\gamma\ge0$, I can see this. In fact $||M_t||\le C \frac{\exp(\gamma t)-1}{\gamma t}$ which implies the above for $\gamma\ge0$. I can not see how the above bound can be obtained for $\gamma\lt 0$.

Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's implicitly assumed that $\gamma \geq 0$, since otherwise you get that the semigroup decreases to 0 exponentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
     \|M_tx\| \le \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\|Q(s)x\|ds \\
               \le \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\gamma s}ds\cdot C\|x\|.
$$
The integral is the mean value of $e^{\gamma s}$ for $s \in [0,t]$, which is bounded by $e^{\gamma t}$ if $\gamma > 0$; but this would not be the case if $\gamma < 0$. You can test with the case $Q(s) = e^{\gamma s}I$; in this case
$$
     M_t x=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\gamma s}ds\; x
$$
For $\gamma < 0$, this is not bounded by $e^{\gamma t}\|x\|$. So, if this is to hold, then I suspect they are assuming $\gamma > 0$.